# MD Character Count Duplicate Display Issue

Tags: add-on, control-panel, extension

Just installed MD Character Count on a site. Everything is working as expected, with the exception of the extension's output. It's duplicating on render. See the attached screenshot for an example. Curious if anyone familiar with this add-on has crossed this bridge before. Thanks[image]

Comment: Don't have an answer, but you might try an alternative: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/limitee